# To show $B^2$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ be a non singular matrix with distinct eigenvalues,  $B$ is a matrix such that $AB= BA^{-1}$, we need to show square of B is diagonalizable.

I tried to show that Square of B commutes with A which has distinct eigenvalues and hence square of B is diagonalizable, but I was not able to do that. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $B = ABA = A^{-1}BA^{-1}$, hence
$$ B^2A = B(A^{-1}BA^{-1})A = BA^{-1}B = (ABA)A^{-1}B = AB^2
$$

Comment: What a tricky calculation, thanks

Comment: You can also use that (multiply $AB = BA^{-1}$ from the left with $A^{-1}$ and from the right with $A$) $BA = A^{-1}B$ and then directly $$ AB^2 = BA^{-1}B = B^2A $$